# How to change detail band color when group changes?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, grouping, ireport

I have a category and customer table as you seen below in my database:

[image]

Then i want to make report from these tables and grouping by `category id` in jasper. this is my `jrxml` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="jasper" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <queryString language="plsql">
        <![CDATA[select c.cid as "CID", c.title, j.id, j.name, j.family
  from Jasper j
  join Category c
    on j.c_id = c.cid]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CID" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TITLE" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="FAMILY" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <group name="category">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{CID}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="212" height="0"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                </frame>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="33" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="196" y="1" width="162" height="32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Consolas" size="20" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Jasper]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="213" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#F0F0F0"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Consolas"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="313" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#F0F0F0"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Consolas"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="413" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#F0F0F0"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Consolas"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Family]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="1" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#F0F0F0"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Consolas"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[CID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="101" y="0" width="112" height="20" backcolor="#F0F0F0"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Consolas"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Title]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="213" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Consolas"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="313" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Consolas"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="413" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Consolas"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{FAMILY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="100" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{category_COUNT}.longValue() == 1 ? true : false)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Consolas"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{CID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="101" y="0" width="112" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{category_COUNT}.longValue() == 1 ? true : false)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Consolas"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{TITLE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="101" y="0" width="112" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Result of this file is like this:

[image]

But i want ti have result like this:

[image]

**How can i do that?**

Comment: Something happened with the images...

Comment: Sorry, its my fault, i couldnt see the images.

Comment: Oh, could you give me your email to send images to your email? this is my email address: rasool_ghafary@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional style.
Define style like this:

```
<style name="myStyle">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
    </box>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[($F{CID} % 2) != 0]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFF00"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[($F{CID} % 2) == 0]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

Put all fields in detail section into frame and set this style for frame.

This describe in iReportUltimateGuide at section "Working with Styles"

Comment: If the Category get to deleted, then this solution does not work correclty. for example if category id's like this: **1,2,4**

Comment: Use variables of JR. For instance
`<variable name="GROUPORDERNUM" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="DistinctCount">
  <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{CID}]]></variableExpression>
  <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
 </variable>`